# SvgToPdf throwing error

Tags: javascript, jspdf

I am using jsPddf.js to generate pdf on client side. 
I have a svg pie chart on my page, to print that on pdf I am using svgToPdf.js plugin.
But I am getting the following error in my browser console :

Uncaught TypeError: Illegal constructor

Code which is causing the error : var fillRGB = new RGBColor(fillColor);

Following is the code to generate pdf from svg :

```
        function createPdf() {
            var svg = $('#completed svg').get(0);
            var doc = new jsPDF();

            doc.text(20, 20, 'This is the default font.');

            doc.setFont("courier");
            doc.text(20, 30, 'This is courier normal.');

            doc.setFont("times");
            doc.setFontType("italic");
            doc.text(20, 40, 'This is times italic.');

            doc.setFont("helvetica");
            doc.setFontType("bold");
            doc.text(20, 50, 'This is helvetica bold.');

            doc.setFont("courier");
            doc.setFontType("bolditalic");
            doc.text(20, 60, 'This is courier bolditalic.');

            svgElementToPdf(svg, doc, {
                //cale: 72 / 96, // this is the ratio of px to pt units
                removeInvalid: true // this removes elements that could not be translated to pdf from the source svg
            });

            doc.save('Test.pdf');
        }
```

Answer (score 3):

svgElementToPdf uses a class RGBColor for color parsing which probably is the reason that is causing you the problem. You can get that class from [here](http://www.phpied.com/files/rgbcolor/rgbcolor.js)

Just add the javascript file to your javascript assets and you will probably be good to go.

Also, to read more about it, please refer [here](http://www.phpied.com/rgb-color-parser-in-javascript/)